# BigQuery - joining on a repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a join on a repeated field.

Originally I get an error:

```
Cannot join on repeated field payload.pages.action
```

I fix this by running flatten on the relevant table (this is only an example query - it will give empty result if it would successfully run):

```
SELECT 
  t1.repository.forks
FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested t1
left join each flatten(publicdata:samples.github_nested,payload.pages) t2 
on t2.payload.pages.action=t1.repository.url
```

I get a different error:

```
Table wildcard function 'FLATTEN' can only appear in FROM clauses
```

This used to work in the past. Is there some syntax change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there has been a syntax change, but you should be able to wrap the flatten statement in a subselect. That is,

```
SELECT 
  t1.repository.forks
FROM publicdata:samples.github_nested t1
left join each (SELECT * FROM flatten(publicdata:samples.github_nested,payload.pages)) t2 
on t2.payload.pages.action=t1.repository.url
```

Comment: This would cost much more (due to select *). I know this syntax worked in the past because I had a saved query I've been running successfully in the past (see job 507322187707:job_sn66jvuPWf4phohbV7JW7R81MIg for exact query).

Comment: Maybe this was broken/changed when adding table wildcard functionality?

Comment: The select * here won't actually end up charging you more because we eliminate columns that aren't used in the rest of the query. If you try typing the query into the web ui it will show you how many bytes will actually get processed. That said, I'll look into why the syntax you used isn't working.